# How do I get my Epson Scanner working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: printing, scanner

I have the Epson SX218 with a built-in scanner. The printer works fine but if I want to scan something simple scan says no scanner found.

Any ideas what I can do?

*By the way, how can I check the ink level of the printer??*

Comment: I use simple scan. How do I install the scanner driver?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using iscan with my epson that you can download from epson website (I checked and it's compatible with yours also).

Please note that if you want to connect to your printer through network and not directly (like usb) you have to install the network package (both downloads on [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=27427&DSCCHK=088aed7d31a621dc6c3ebfbefd9d4dcce571416a)) and change the epkowa.conf file as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439031/iscan-doesnt-work-with-epson-wf-3520).

For any doubts or information on the installations needed you can visit epson FAQ on [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00002.html).

Comment: epson link no longer works

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1487133/14650 for a solution working for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It also explains how to find the updated links.