# iscan doesn't work with Epson WF-3520

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm trying to use iscan to scan some documents from my printer epson WF-3520. The problem is that if I try to run iscan program I get the following message:

**Could not send command to scanner.
Check the scanner's status.**

I already tried to open it from terminal: `sudo iscan` and I get the same result.

I am able to use the program Simple Scan to scan through my printer but only using the flatbed. If I try to use the document feeder the program freezes and the printer goes crazy forcing me to restart her. Also Simple Scan lacks many of the functionality of the iscan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to use the name of the printer in the `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` file.

For example `net EPSON0xxxx.local` instead of an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

For the record.
My scanner Epson Workforve WF-7610 was not recognized by iscan yet xsane recognized it.

```
sudo -u saned scanimage -L
```

returned

```
device `epson2:net:192.168.1.30' is a Epson PID 08B9 flatbed scanner
```

but it did not work.
It used to work flawlsssly with the same configuration BEFORE upgrading to 17.10.

My workaround:

1. Commented epson2 and epson in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` . I added epkowa.
2. `epkowa.conf` has the correct net ip.
3. I copied epkowa drivers to correct lib folder

   ```
   cp /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa.* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

- Fire up the printer.
- Install the printer first before installing the scanner!
- print a test page
- print a network settings page (most printers can do that)

It is very important to give the printer/scanner a fixed or barely used (higher ranges) IP address or this might not work!

Look for network information of the printer/scanner you want to work with. You can also look in the log of the router for the dhcp assigned ip address.

- Write down the details of this address, DNS, name, the lot or print it.
- Give the printer a static address. This might work from the printer panel or form the browser setup menu using the ip address you discovered before.
  Just type that IP address in any browser and the printer menu should open.
- Where to change the IP? Probably in advanced settings. Might diver from your specific printer but it might be something like:
  network basic.
- If a static address is no option assign a ip address in the higher ranges.

It is important to assign a static IP or high-range IP address!

- Install the right driver for the right printer here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX
  Install the deb file as described:
- go to folder and unpack (using file manager)
- go to terminal and move to folder

  ```
  sudo ./install.sh
  ```
- Then:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
  ```
- add the IP address where it says network;

  ```
  net (place here the static ip you just made, it should look like net 192.168 etc)

  sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epson2.conf
  ```
- add the IP address where it says network;

  ```
  net (place here the static ip you just made)

  sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
  ```

  add epkowa (as suggested in the excellent explanation mentioned above)

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa.* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/
  ```

  Optional:

  ```
  sudo service udev restart
  ```

  type:

  ```
  iscan
  ```

It should work now.

Setting up an Epson printer and the Iscan network scanner has always been a pain in the ass. Even when using Ubuntu 18 but this might work.

Comment: I have a Epson SX235W and to just have the scanner working via network, I just had to install the `iscan` bundle (untar the `iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz`, run the `install.sh`), install the network plugin (inside the previous archive, there's a `plugins` folder with a `iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb` inside, install this `.deb` with `dpkg -i <package>`), and edit the `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` file, adding a line `net <IP-of-your-printer>`.

Note: You can get the current IP of your printer by running `scanimage -L`. Use DHCP to fix your printer IP.