# How do I get iScan to detect my Epson network Scanner?

Tags: networking, drivers, scanner, epson

I would like to install my Epson Scanner ( model WP-4535 ) in Ubuntu 16.04 (had it installed in 15.10).

I installed this

```
sudo apt-get install sane libltdl7
```

then iScan from the epsonpage (1), which is supposed to be an all-in-one package. I installed it via `./install.sh` which results in having the following iscan parts:

```
x@y:~$ dpkg -l iscan* | grep ii
ii  iscan                2.30.3-1     amd64        simple, easy to use scanner utility for EPSON scanners
ii  iscan-data           1.39.0-1     all          Image Scan! for Linux data files
ii  iscan-network-nt     1.1.1-1      amd64        Image Scan! Network Plugin
```

iScan still cannot communicate with the scanner, though it can be identified via the following command

```
scanimage -L
device `epson2:net:192.168.0.7' is a Epson PID 087D flatbed scanner
```

If I recall it from 15.10 (worked after hours of *meh*) , epkowa was the solution not epson2, but adding it manually via 
    sudo nano /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
doesn't work.

The  ubuntuuser page (2), suggests installing ltdl7 packages, which seems to be important, but I have no clue, how to find it (same with the *plugin*):

```
iscan_2.X.X-1.ltdl7_i386.deb (32 bit) / iscan_2.X.X-1.ltdl7_amd64.deb (64 bit)

ggf. iscan-plugin-gt-1500_2.1.2-1_i386.deb (allgemein iscan-plugin-SCANNER_VERSION_ARCHITEKTUR.deb) oder z.B. etwas wie esci-interpreter-perfection-v330_0.1.1-2_i386.deb
```

Also installed  xsltproc (3), because of reasons, but didn't change it.

Any suggestions?; help appreciated!

(1): hxxp://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=1.0.4

(2): hxxps://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Hardware/Epson/#Verwendung-von-iScan

(3): hxxps://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Epson/

Comment: Thanks to @belyid (1) I found the reason, in one of the dozen tabs I had opened during my research, while I was running with my head through a wall - edited epkowa.conf and added the ip of the scanner in the network, resulting in scanimage -L to mention epkowa, finding a scanner, and iscan to work with my printer. Thanks and out (1) http://askubuntu.com/questions/436516/how-do-i-get-my-epson-scanner-working-on-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Welcome to **Stackexchange**.  This is a question and answer site.  Editing the question and adding solved doesn't work in this format.  If you have a answer to your question you are free to answer it.  Click on the **Answer** part and type the answer there.  This is the method on this forum that allows the users to know there is an answer to the questions when searching for solutions to issues.  Please visit http://askubuntu.com/tour for other tips on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Due to instant feedback, I post my comment as an answer - if you consider this a duplicate, feel free to delete - I still think, I shouldn't have to browse about 2 hours through different pages to install my *"$§%/( scanner in ubuntu, after this issue has been around for 2 1/2 years, though this probably isn't due to Ubuntu itself and surely not a problem of this community in particular...

> Thanks to @belyid (1) I found the reason, in one of the dozen tabs I had opened during my research, while I was running with my head through a wall - edited epkowa.conf and added the ip of the scanner in the network, resulting in scanimage -L to mention epkowa, finding a scanner, and iscan to work with my printer. Thanks and out

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1487133/14650 for a solution working for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.